# How to achieve url redirection in glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, redirect

I have an application running on Glassfish 3 server. I need to redirect any user who accesses my application to another url. For ex-  abc.def.com:8080/abc/index.html to xyz.def.com:8080/abc/index.html   I tried doing it by adding property in my Glassfish Configuration Server-config > Edit Virtual Server > Add Property name=redirect_1 value="from=abc.def.com:8080/abc/index.html url-prefix=http://xyz.def.com:8080/abc/index.html" But it dint work. 
Could anyone suggest how to create such redirect ? Or is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is too late, but this can help others.
I had the same problem last week, but in my case, all server was redirected. In this case, I just create one cache server filter. In my case, I need various items on filter, but to only redirect, you just need the "SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY" block... This is my code:

```
 @WebFilter("/faces/*")
public class CacheFilter implements Filter, Serializable {
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
    System.out.println("Cache Filter initated");
  }
  private boolean useFilter = false;
  private boolean useCache = false;
  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException{
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
    if(!useCache){
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
      response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
      response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);// don't create if it doesn't exist
    System.out.println("session is " + session);
    if(session!=null&&!session.isNew()){
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }else{
      String url = "/"+Server.AMBIENTE.getName()+"/faces/prod/index.xhtml";
      System.out.println("url: " + url);
      boolean redirect = false;
      System.out.println("requested url: " + request.getRequestURI());
      if(!request.getRequestURI().equals(url) && redirect){
        //System.out.println("SEND REDIRECT");
        //response.sendRedirect(url);
        System.out.println("SEND REDIRECT TO ANOTHER SITE");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.google.com.br/");
      }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
//        } catch (final Exception ex) {
//            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/server/v4/template/expirated.xhtml");
//        }catch(final Throwable ex){
//            System.out.println("");
//        }
//        }
  }
  @Override
  public void destroy(){
    // If you have assigned any expensive resources as field of
    // this Filter class, then you could clean/close them here.
  }
}
```